# Access Object with Same Name as Item in Array -- Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, javascript-objects

**PLEASE SEE UPDATE BELOW**

I have an array with the following values:

```
tablet, desktop, widescreen, fullhd
```

I also have objects with the same names.  I am trying to create a `forEach` loop that will use the different names in the array to access certain properties on the objects with the same name.  Something like this:

```
  ['tablet', 'desktop', 'widescreen', 'fullhd'].forEach(type => {
      css`@media screen and (min-width: ${breakpoints[type]}) {
        color: ${type[color]};
        background-color: ${type[bg]};
      }
    `;
  })}
```

The problem is when I try to access `type[color]` or `type[bg]`.  In this case, I am trying to use `type` to reference an object called `tablet`, or `desktop`, etc.  However, I am trying to do so using the strings `tablet`, `desktop`, etc. -- and that does not work.

So, here is my question...

How can I rewrite my code so that I can loop through the values of the array to access the relevant properties on my objects with the same name?

---

**UPDATE**

Here is my full code.  Before I show the code, though, I should note that in this particular example, I am using ReactJS and Styled Components.  However, as far as I know, the question has nothing to do with either React or Styled Components -- it's a pure Javascript question:

First, a breakpoints object:

```
const breakpoints = {
  tablet: "769px",
  desktop: "1024px",
  widescreen: "1216px",
  fullhd: "1408px"
};
```

Secondly, I create an array based off of the keys of that object:

```
const breakpointKeys = Object.keys(breakpoints);
```

Third, I create a function that uses that array to try and access another object (more on that below):

```
const gridCSS = ({ bg, color, tablet }) => css`
  background-color: ${bg};
  color: ${color};
  ${breakpointKeys.forEach(key => {
    css`
      @media screen and (min-width: ${breakpoints[key]}) {
        color: ${key[color]};
        background-color: ${key[bg]};
      }
    `;
  })}
```

Fourth, I create a Styled Component that uses that function (`${gridCSS}`):

```
const Grid = styled.div(
  ({ color, bg, desktop, tablet }) => css`
  display: grid;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  ${gridCSS}
`
);
```

Fifth, I create a React Component with a number of props (note, in particular, the `tablet` and the `desktop` props):

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Grid
      color="orange"
      bg="lightgreen"

      tablet={{
        color: "green",
        bg: "orange"
      }}

      desktop={{
        color: "yellow",
        bg: "purple"
      }}
    >
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
        <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      </div>
    </Grid>
  );
}
```

The props `tablet` and `desktop` are the objects that I am trying to get access to from my `breakpointsKeys` array.

Comment: You should access value from that object like this, `object[type][bg]` ? can you please show how your object looks like ?

Comment: How about using eval to get the object. Something like: let obj = eval(type);

Comment: e.g. have an object with properties with these names, that acts as an index. `const index = { tablet, desktop, widescreen, fullhd }; index[type][color];`

Comment: Well why not have an array with the objects in them? Either instead of the strings, or alongside that array. That way the index value passed in to the `.forEach()` callback can be used to access the actual object.

Comment: I have updated my question to show the exact code that I am using -- in case that helps.

Comment: So I wasted my time guessing at a way to help you and you post tons of extra code, making my attempt a waste of time

Comment: @mplungjan I'm sorry if my original question was not detailed enough.  That is why I updated it.

Comment: `${key[color]}` is not valid. Add color to the breakpoint object and do `${breakpoints[key].color}` etc using `tablet: { "bp":"769px", "color":"red",...}`

Comment: @mplungjan Adding the colors to the breakpoints object is not an option.  I need the color values to be added to the props.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a solution that worked.  Here is the code:

```
const gridCSS = ({ bg, textColor, ...props }) => {
  let mediaQueryCSS = breakpointKeys.map(key => {
    let mediaQuery = breakpoints[key].value + breakpoints[key].unit;

    return css`
      @media screen and (min-width: ${mediaQuery}) {
        color: ${props[key] && props[key].textColor};
        background-color: ${props[key] && props[key].bg};
      }
    `;
  });

  return css`
    background-color: ${bg};
    color: ${textColor};
    ${mediaQueryCSS};
  `;
};
```

Changing from `forEach` to `map` is related to Styled Components.

I think the reason this works is because instead of destructing the props off of the `props` object, I instead reference `props` and then reference `key` off of `props` (as noted in the comments by 'Code Maniac'.  That way, I am not calling an object with a string, but rather a property off of an object with a string.

Either way, it works.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `eval()`:

```
eval(type).color
eval(type).bg
```